# Text cut in text area in ASP.net page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i'm trying to load text from database into many text fields 
every thing is Ok , but one field of them text lenght is more than the length of the text field 
so not all the text appear on the screen 
that is my ASP.net code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="descriptiont" runat="server" Rows="3" Width="300px" Height="100px" Wrap="true">
```

and that is the code behind of it

```
descriptiont.Text = s.GetValue(1).ToString();
descriptiont.Enabled = false;
```

and that is what i get in the web page 
[image: text field not appear well]

the orginal text is "ECASTI (Egyptian Center for the Advancement of Science, Technology, and Innovation) "

can any one help ??!!!

Comment: It seems there is some css around. Can you give the actual html and css?

Comment: It is css problem. In your css set this property for textbox.         word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Then you can access the content via:

```
string message= TextArea1.Text;
```

Answer (score 6):

Dont fix the height of textbox. Height should be auto.And in css add property for textbox. It will work.

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: it's true but you need to explain more about it

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
string s = "Your Text Field";
        if (s.Length > 20)
        {
            //Change Width="450px"
        }
```

Update :

You can aslo change width in CSS when text length is more than the length of the field.

Update 2 :

You can resize the textbox in C# with the following codes :

```
        if (s.Length>20)
        {
            textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        }

    void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
        textBox1.Width = size.Width;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the length of the textbox, may be it will mess up your design, add a textbox tool tip with the same content. So when you hover on textbox it will display the full content.

```
descriptiont.Text = s.GetValue(1).ToString();
descriptiont.Title = s.GetValue(1).ToString();
descriptiont.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is property of textbox named "TextMode". Please add 'TextMode="multiline"'
in your view or you can add it from your code behind file also.